# SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting error after update @capacitor-firebase/messaging to 5 version

Tags: reactjs, apple-m1, capacitor

After I updated the @capacitor-firebase/messaging package to version 5, I started encountering an error like this:

```
warning: Run script build phase 'Copy GoogleService-Info.plist' will be run during every build because it does
        not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or
        configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target
        'App' from project 'App')
        warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not
        specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure
        it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'App' from
        project 'App')
        ** BUILD FAILED **
        
        
        The following build commands failed:
        SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ App (in target 'App' from project 'App')
        (1 failure)
```

I suspect that it's somehow related to the fact that my MacBook runs on the M1 architecture, but I can't seem to get rid of this persistent error when building my emulator.

Comment: You need to post the full output. These are only warnings, not the actual error.

Comment: @RGe Oke, but it's quite big, I can show the part, and I guess the reason is that after update it deleted Firebase from pods file, and therefore canno't import it in AppDelegate.swift

Comment: I will post answer if it works